# php simple html dom parser doesn't return anything

Tags: php, html-parsing, simpledom

Why won't my script return the div with the id of "pp-featured"?

```
<?php
# create and load the HTML  
include('lib/simple_html_dom.php');  
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->load("http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=6703996311168776503&q=hills+garage&hl=en&view=feature&mcsrc=google_reviews&num=20&start=0&ved=0CFUQtQU&sa=X&ei=sCq_Tr3mJZToygTOmuCGCg");  

$ret = $html->find('div[id=pp-featured]');

# output it!  
echo $ret->save();
?>
```

Comment: What does `echo $ret;` yield?

Comment: Normally in CSS the selector would be `div[id="pp-featured"]`, not sure if this class you're using is strict about that. But if you're looking for an ID, why not just use `div#pp-featured`? Does this class not support that?

Comment: @animuson I was just using the example in the manual. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: What do you mean by word array? Does it not output the HTML?

Comment: no it doesn't. It's only that word.

Comment: simple html dom allways returns an array. try a var_dump($ret).

Comment: @thew that didn't work either.

Comment: What does it return? An empty array?

Comment: I still don't understand. Which word do you mean?

Comment: @pekka all echo $ret; yields is the word "array" that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this gets me on my way. Thanks for your help.

```
<?php

include_once 'lib/simple_html_dom.php';

$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=6703996311168776503&q=hills+garage&hl=en&view=feature&mcsrc=google_reviews&num=20&start=0&ved=0CFUQtQU&sa=X&ei=sCq_Tr3mJZToygTOmuCGCg";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$ret =  $html->find('div[id=pp-reviews]');

foreach($ret as $story)
    echo $story;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The library always returns an array because it may be possible that more than one item matches the selector.

If you expect only one you should check to ensure the page your analyzing is behaving as expected.

Suggested solution:

```
<?php

include_once 'lib/simple_html_dom.php';

$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=6703996311168776503&q=hills+garage&hl=en&view=feature&mcsrc=google_reviews&num=20&start=0&ved=0CFUQtQU&sa=X&ei=sCq_Tr3mJZToygTOmuCGCg";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$ret =  $html->find('div[id=pp-reviews]');
if(count($ret)==1){
echo $ret[0]->save();
}
else{
echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

Comment: Getting this error : Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in ...